# Submit is not working

Tags: asp.net

I'm using dynamic controls at my ASP.NET applications. So the issue is - when I use these controls separatelly - they work well. But when I put these two controls on the same page - ONLY LAST submit event is fired. Could anyone help me to identify where is the issue and how to fix it?

Here is my aspx layout:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="MYPAGE.ascx.cs" Inherits="MYNAMESPACE" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="MYANOTHERNAMESPACE" Namespace="MYNAMESPACE" TagPrefix="DAControl" %>

...
 <div>
     <DAControl:ChooseImageDialog runat="server" id="ChooseImageDialog" />
     <DAControl:ChooseVideoDialog runat="server" id="ChooseVideoDialog" />
 </div>
```

Here is my 1st control:

```
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:ChooseImageDialog runat=server></{0}:ChooseImageDialog>")]
    public class ChooseImageDialog : WebControl
    {
        /* This is only part of my code, which should enough for explaining the issue*/

        private Button applyPreview = new Button();
        private Button cancelPreview = new Button();

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            applyPreview.Click += new EventHandler(applyPreview_Click);

            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        void applyPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // I want to reach this block
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my 2nd control:

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:ChooseVideoDialog runat=server></{0}:ChooseVideoDialog>")]
    public class ChooseVideoDialog : WebControl
    {
        /* This is only part of my code, which should enough for explaining the issue*/
        private Button applyVideoPreview = new Button();
        private Button cancelPreview = new Button();

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {    
            applyVideoPreview.Click += new EventHandler(ApplyPreviewVideo_Click);

            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        void ApplyPreviewVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // I want to reach this block
        }

    }
```

Comment: add "protected " before return type...

Comment: by "...which should enough for explaining the issue", do you mean that you still encounter the problem when reducing your two controls to these parts of code ? What do you mean exactly with "ONLY LAST submit event is fired" ?

Comment: Yes, I still encounter the problem when reducing my two controls to these parts of code.I mean that I have two submit buttons, but works only last, which placed at 2nd control. But if I change declaration order at .aspx file - then only 1st will work.

Comment: Using your code, I obtain a working solution. I guess it might come from the moment you add your buttons to your control, which does not appear in your code (I do it as the first line in onload ; on init would be even better I guess) Is your MyPage.ascx dynamically added to the page ? You should then provide the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Events must be wired up in the Init event. Any later in the life cycle is too late.

Comment: Ok, I tried to do it at Init event, but still no luck... Anyway these controls are works. The issue is only when I put these to controls on on the same page.